# Adding `"type": "module"` in `package.json` breaks path resolutions in React Native: Unable to resolve module

Tags: typescript, react-native

I've been using `babel-plugin-module-resolver` to use aliases in a React Native project since a few months, but since I added `"type": "module"` to my `package.json`, at the moment I launch my app (`npm run ios`), Metro is unable to resolve my dependencies using aliases:

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module /path/to/my/project/packages/core from /path/to/my/project/packages/storybook-mobile/index.js

None of these files exist:
  * ../core(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * ../core/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx
```

As a side note, it might be important to mention that I'm working on a monorepo, explaining the `/packages/` in my path.
And again, everything was working fine before I added `"type": "module"` to my `package.json`.

This is my `babel.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        extensions: [
          '.ios.ts',
          '.android.ts',
          '.ts',
          '.ios.tsx',
          '.android.tsx',
          '.tsx',
          '.jsx',
          '.js',
          '.svg',
          '.png',
          '.jpg',
          '.webp',
          '.json',
        ],
        alias: {
          '@treezor/core': path.resolve(__dirname, 'packages/core'),
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

And this is my `compilerOptions` in my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@treezor/core": ["./packages/core/src"],
    }
  }
```

And in `index.js`, the line breaking the app is the following:

```js
import { dictionary } from '@treezor/core';
```

But removing that dependency only moves the error to the following import using an alias.

Does anyone know why simply adding `"type": "module"` to my `package.json` would break the aliases?